# Unwanted padding on ListViewItem in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I have created a ListView which is binded to desired items.

However, on each ListViewItem there is unwanted padding which i have checked in XAML visual preview (12,0,0,0)

However, I haven't found any way to set the padding to 0 for ListViewItem or ViewCell as they don't have those properties accessable. They are only accessable through xaml live visual preview.

Is there any way to remove the unwanted padding?

I'll include the picture for visualization (ListView has red background, and children have blue background)
[Picture showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45NT6.png)

`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="Red">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Blue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Hello World"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

EDIT:

The Version of maui is 6.0.400 and Visual Studio Preview 17.3 Version 2.0

Comment: If you do `<Grid ... BackgroundColor="Green">`, does the red change to green?

Comment: No, it just makes the background color green all the way to the right. The red background because of padding (12,0,0,0) with color red of ListView remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug related to MAUI version 6.0.400 and 6.0.312.

It works correctly on 6.0.300-rc.3.5667

Closing question.